# how to hash an array of address?

Tags: solidity, keccak

I want to hash a given array  of address (using keccak256) into a single variable byte32.

for example:

```
function hashOfArray( address [] list) public constant returns (byte32) {
      var hash = ...
     return hash;
}
```

Comment: `keccak256(list)` should work well

Comment: but keccak256(list) != keccak256(list[0],..,list[n])

Comment: @maroodb that won't make a difference if you are going to compare hashes.

Comment: Also, are you sure `keccak256(list) != keccak256(list[0], ... list[n])`? I believe it should be, and in my testing it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keccak256(list) to compare 2 arrays.

The hash will be the same only if the two arrays have the same size and the same content in the same order.

I wrote a smart contract where we can test that:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Test {

    function cond1() pure internal returns (bool) {
        // same array with different content
        uint[] memory array_a = new uint[](1);
        bytes32 hash1 = keccak256(array_a);
        array_a[0] = 42;
        bytes32 hash2 = keccak256(array_a);
        // hashes should be different
        return hash1 != hash2;
    }

    function cond2() pure internal returns (bool) {
        // different arrays with same size and content
        uint[] memory array_a = new uint[](1);
        uint[] memory array_b = new uint[](1);
        array_a[0] = 42;
        array_b[0] = 42;
        // hashes should be equal
        return keccak256(array_a) == keccak256(array_b);
    }

    function cond3() pure internal returns (bool) {
        // empty arrays with different sizes
        uint[] memory array_a = new uint[](1);
        uint[] memory array_b = new uint[](2);
        // hashes should be different
        return keccak256(array_a) != keccak256(array_b);
    }

    function cond4() pure internal returns (bool) {
        // same content, in different order
        uint[] memory array_a = new uint[](2);
        uint[] memory array_b = new uint[](2);
        array_a[0] = 42; array_a[1] = 17;
        array_b[0] = 17; array_a[1] = 42;
        // hashes should be different
        return keccak256(array_a) != keccak256(array_b);
    }

    function testConditions() pure public returns (bool) {
        return cond1() && cond2() && cond3() && cond4();
    }
}
```

Calling testConditions() will return true.